# Catch the value input field with Javascript and put it in destination URL

Tags: javascript

My website is almost ready but i still have to integrate something for the search-functionallity.

The search-page is working good and has this URL:

www.mywebsite.be/search/node/

Ofcourse there should be also the search-term in the url, something like this:

www.mywebsite.be/search/node/search-term

And that is my problem/question... Adding the search-term to the destination url...

```
<!-- START Search form-->
    <?php          
        $searchterm = 'parket';
    ?>
     <form action='/search/node/<?php print $searchterm; ?>' method='POST' role="search" class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
           <input name="searchtest" type="text" placeholder="Schrijf hier" class="form-control">
           <div data-toggle="navbar-search-dismiss" class="fa fa-times form-control-feedback"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="hidden btn btn-default"></button>
     </form>
     <!-- END Search form-->
```

As you can see, i put in the search-term hard coded in with PHP... Like this the search-form works... So the only thing left to do is, catch the search-term that the visitor puts in and put this in the destination url...

You can see a not working example of this code here:

www.woodtex.be

1. The visitors clicks the search icon and the input-field is appaering..
2. The visitor types in his search-term
3. The visitor hits ENTER (no search-button!)
4. And then the search term should be catched and put in the detsination-url

I think this can be done with javascript, but i'm not in ninja JS man :(

So any tips/code/links are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_action(form) {
        form.action = 'www.mywebsite.be/search/node/'+form.search.value;

    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="get_action(this);"action="">
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Suchit this works fine! Although only in "Safari" browser... In Chrome and Firefox it doesn't... There the "search-term" is not showing up in the url... But i will work further on it... @suchit

Comment: no in firefox it will work for sure because i have tested there.just check your version.

Comment: I also tried your code in a blank HTML page, and then it works indeed in all browsers, so i think it's the some code in my template... I gonna check it and integrate in a live website..

Comment: @StanKosmoseistis if your problem is solved just mark it as answer.

Comment: Almost there i hope... Your solutions works in a clean html-file. But in my website online it only works in safari. www.woodtex.be Still looking around, learning and try to find the problem ;-) @suchit

Comment: alert(form.search.value); in this function and see whether it is coming or not.if not then use document.getElementById('search').value;

Comment: Same problem with the alert-function... In safari the value is showing up in warning, but not in Chrome or Firefox. With "document.getElementById" also working only in Safari... In clean html file it works in all 3 browsers. So your/code solutions is correct.. so I marked your answer... the problem is in my other code ;-) ..; gonna look for it. Thanks a lot @suchit

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I've never used PHP, but you could try this:

```
var currString = "<?php echo $searchterm ?>"
window.location.search += currString;
```